# Using php to interpret message from parallel port

Tags: php, apache

Right now I'm working on a program in php that is going to take in an error message from another computer via the parallel port and basically display the message.  I have never messed with parallel port access before, and am not sure what exactly I need to be doing.  I was wondering how possible and easy this task will be and which direction I should turn to.

I'm not completely clear on the details (I'll update when I completely find out), but from my understanding the computer is going to act like it's printing the file and the php code is going to grab the message and just display it on a regular web page.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There is no buit-in PHP function to communicate through LPT, Serial Port, USB or other peripheral communication interface.
2. However, you can execute certain executables calling them via **exec**, **system** or **passthru**
3. The executable can be a program which communicates with an external device.

Comment: Thanks, glad to find this out before I wasted days trying to figure out how to access the thing.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be using an external program (Delphi or VisualBasic for example) that will read from parallel port and write/append to a file located in the web server folder.

The PHP script can then easily access and read that messages file.